# what is actually 1073741819 ? ( in Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) )

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am new at coding. I code c++ in codeblocks . I don't understand what actually 1073741819 is? Is this a range of memory or something else. Please Help..

Comment: Likely an indication the variable has not been properly assigned a value yet.

Comment: Codeblocks, I understand, is an IDE (for Fortran & C++).  What does that have to do with C++?  How are you getting the error message?

Comment: That's a generic "access violation" error in Windows, usually caused by a NULL or otherwise invalid pointer. Why that might happen depends on the context and code that are not shown.

Comment: Google 0xC0000005

Comment: I believe there may also be a misunderstanding on your part about the relationship between the two values. 0xC0000005 is the hexadecimal representation of the eight byte signed integer -1073741819.

Comment: But why only 1073741819 ?? Why not anything else??

Answer (score 3):

`0xC0000005` is the error code for an Access Violation exception.  Windows throws that exception when code tries to access invalid memory.

So, the error message "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" means an Access Violation exception occured in the context of the program's main thread and was not caught by the program's code, thus causing the program's `main()`/`WinMain()` entry point to exit prematurely, terminating the process.